# convergence in law of Cauchy random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

$(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of random variables independent and identically distributed with Cauchy distribution of parameter $\alpha$ ,  $\alpha > 0$.

Let 
$$
Y_n= \dfrac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k}{n}.
$$
How to prove that $(Y_n)_{ n \geq 1 }$ converge in law to random variable $Z$ such that $\dfrac{1}{Z}$ has an exponential distribution?

So 
\begin{align*}
F_{Y_n}(y)=&  \mathbb{P}(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k \leq n y) \\
          =&  \mathbb{P}(X_k \leq n y, \, \forall k, \, 1 \leq k \leq n)  \\
          =&  (F_{X_1}(ny))^n \\
          =&   \left(\dfrac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\dfrac{ny}{\alpha}) + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n \\
          \sim & \left(1+ \dfrac{\alpha}{y}\dfrac{1}{n} \right)^n \\
          =& \exp \dfrac{\ln \left(1+ \dfrac{\alpha}{ny}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}
         \rightarrow & e^{\dfrac{\alpha}{y}}
\end{align*}
But the last expression is not a cumulative fonction.
I'm very grateful if a kindly sool should be answer this question.

Comment: $\arctan(\frac{ny}{\alpha})$ does not behave like $\frac{ny}{\alpha}$ for large $n$.

Comment: and in fact for large $x$, $\arctan(x) \approx \dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac1x$

Comment: @Henry  Thank's, So I have improve it